# C++ fin.getline, multi dimensional array resources?

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files, getline

for my CS class.. cant use vectors!  Ive searched everywhere for some information on how to read in lines of string from a txt into a two-d or 3d array and i cant find ANyTHING. i need some help please.

reading in a text file that looks like this:

- what is the capital of texas?
- austin
- kansas
- harlingen
- dupont
- blankline
- blankline
- what is the capital of maine?
- etc
- etc

so its blocks: 1 question 4 answers,  two empty lines, repeat.

my array to store 50 questions, each with 5 lines

```
string questions[50][5];
```

my function to read in txt file into array

```
void read_questions(string[], string[])
{
ifstream.fin;
fin.open("questions.txt")
while (!fin.eof{}}
fin.getline([i][j];
}
```

i know i am far off but if you can point me to some references i would appreciate. ive looked through many resources and googled many times but cant find any examples close to mine atall. i asked at another site but they keep telling me to use vectors but we cant we have to use a 2d or 3d array

Comment: It probably violates the spirit of the restriction, but you could use a `deque`, `list`, or even `map<int, string>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string questions[50][5];
```

That line declares an array of an array of `string`s.  That's a good enough start.

To read each line in, you'll need:

- A function that reads in a single string
- A loop to read in five strings, and
- A loop to read in fifty sets of five strings

The nested loops are easy:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
  {
    do some work here.
  }
```

Picking an input function is pretty easy, too. You'll want to use `std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&)`.

Comment: inside that loop, you'll want to check for end of file